# typescript react project npm run build works local but fails in CodeBuild

Tags: reactjs, typescript, aws-codepipeline

I have a typescirpt react project that i want to deploy to s3 with cloud front. i tried to use aws codepipeline to deploy my typescript react project to s3. i kept getting the following error in build stage:

```
2022/10/31 08:56:42 Running command npm run build

> web-frontend@0.1.0 build /codebuild/output/src017550065/src
> react-scripts build

/codebuild/output/src017550065/src/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/node_modules/jest-worker/build/index.js:110
  _ending;
         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

here is my `buildspec.yml` file:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: latest
    commands:
      - npm install -g typescript
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - npm run build

artifacts:
  # include all files required to run application
  # notably excluded is node_modules, as this will cause overwrite error on deploy
  files:
    - public/**/*
    - src/**/*
    - package.json
    - appspec.yml
    - scripts/**/*

cache:
  paths:
    - './node_modules/**/*'
```

my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "web-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.66",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-bootstrap-icons": "^1.9.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

the line of code that throwing this error()

```
class Worker {
  _ending;
  _farm;
  _options;
  _workerPool;
```

i tried to edit the buildspec.yml file. change the jsnode version to 10,12 and latest.